# Load Collection with entityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, dao, entitymanager

I got a beer

```
@Entity
@Table(name="beer")
public class Beer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String brewery;
    private String name;

    ...
```

}

and a bottle

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bottle")
public class Bottle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private BottleSize size;

    @ManyToOne
    private Beer beer;

    ...
}
```

and a dao

```
public class BottleDao {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void saveBottle(Bottle bottle) {
        entityManager.persist(bottle);
    }

    public List<Bottle> findByBeer(Beer beer) {
        Bottle foundBottle = entityManager.find(Bottle.class, beer);
        return null;
    }

    public Bottle findById(Long id) {
        Bottle foundBottle = entityManager.find(Bottle.class, id);
        return foundBottle;
    }

}
```

If i run

```
@Test
public void testFindByBeer() throws Exception {
    Beer pils = createHoepfnerPilsner();
    beerDao.saveBeer(pils);
    Beer hefe = createHoepfnerHefe();
    beerDao.saveBeer(hefe);

    Bottle bottlePils = createBottle().withBeer(pils).create();
    bottleDao.saveBottle(bottlePils);
    bottleDao.saveBottle(createBottle().withBeer(hefe).create());

    flushAndClear();
    List<Bottle> bottles = bottleDao.findByBeer(pils);
    assertThat(bottles.size(), is(1));
    assertThat(bottles.get(0).getId(), is(bottlePils.getId()));
}
```

i get the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class Bottle. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class Beer

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that [EntityManager.find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) returns the entity identified by the given ID (primary key). And a bottle is not identified by a beer. It's identified by an ID of type Long.

What you need is a JPQL query:

```
String jpql = "select bottle from Bottle bottle where bottle.beer = :beer";
List<Bottle> bottles = em.createQuery(jpql, Bottle.class)
                         .setParameter("beer", pils)
                         .getResultList();
```

Comment: You are right, i need to search for the id of the beer: Bottle foundBottle = entityManager.find(Bottle.class, beer.getId());

Comment: The code in your comment doesn't make any sense. It looks for a bottle identified by the ID of a beer.

Comment: Hm it has to be possible to do it just with annotations. I read somewhere in the internet, that it would be possible, that em.find() returns a collection. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Why don't you read the javadoc of EntityManager? Isn't it clear that its find() method doesn't return a collection? You can make the association betweeb Beer and Bottle bidirectional, and thus retrieve a beer by its ID, and then call `beer.getBottles()`. Hibernate has a reference documentation. Read it.